# Replace values in pandas dataframe with other on condition

Tags: pandas

i have a dataframe

```
id    main_value
1      10
2      3
4      1
6      10
```

i want to change **main_value** of id = 4,such that it should decrement by 2.

i know a method using .loc

```
freq = 3
if freq == 3:
    df.loc[df.id==4, ['main_value']] = df.main_value.loc[df.id==4] - 2
```

But this seems very lengthy, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
df.loc[df.id==4, 'main_value'] -= 2 
print (df)

   id  main_value
0   1          10
1   2           3
2   4          -1
3   6          10
```

Comment: Yes, this shorcuts is nice, but easy forgetable ;)